# Does this type of function exist?

Tags: complex-analysis

I am struggling with this question:

Determine whether there exists a holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{C}^*\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, such that $$\lim_{r \rightarrow 0}f(re^{i\theta})=e^{i\theta},\forall\theta\in[0,2\pi)$$

I tried to show that it didnt exist. And that follows from the fact that the function has a singularity at 0. It can't be a removable singularity, because as r goes to zero it doesn't tend to a specific value, and it can't be a pole, because it doesn tend to $\infty$. But how can I prove that it is not an essential singularity? I must in some way show that the function is bounded near zero, how do I do that?

Or does it infact exist a function that has this property?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Baire first to get uniform boundedness in an angle, after which you can just blow up, use analiticity to establish uniform continuity in a smaller angle away from the origin and pass to the limit to conclude that $e^{i\theta}$ is analytic on an open set, which is absurd.

Note that the word *every* is crucial here. If you just ask for "almost every" in the sense of the Lebesgue measure, such crazy behavior becomes possible.

Comment: I haven't learned about those concepts you meantion. What do you mean with Baire? Is there a way of solving this with only introductoary complex analysis?

Comment: Baire Category Theorem is the full name (it is just a very smart way to use the nested interval lemma). The answer to your second question is that my ingenuity is insufficient for that, but you can never guarantee that the elementary approach does not exist. All I can guarantee is that it cannot be too simple because of the reason I mentioned in the end of my post.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just to let you know, there might not be an easy way to do this with introductory complex analysis. When we went through the exercise today, the point was that the function was supposed to be bounded around zero. But this is not easy to prove if we don't have uniform convergence when r goes to zero, so there might have been a small mistake in the exercise. Anyway, thanks for your help, I'll try to understand it when I learn more math.

Comment: It is not even true in general if we have just radial limits and that's exactly when Baire comes to the rescue. If it is bounded around zero, it is just a boring exercise about removable singularities and you seemed to have absolutely no problem with it from the start :-).